# Email regex to support all world's emails

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

Since now email address are not only ascii and can be utf8 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531) to support many languages and their alphabets many of the email validation regex I find are too restrictive. I have created the following regex:

```
[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+[.][^@\s]+
```

This regex allows:

`[any_character(s)_except_@_and_whitespace]@[any_character(s)_except_@_and_whitespace].[any_character(s)_except_@_and_whitespace]`

The process I would do to validate an email would be the following:

```
1)Check that the email address is less than 255 characters long.
2)Check that it meets the regex requirements.
3)Check the TLD to make sure it is an ICANN approved domain like .com,
 .mobi, etc (http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt)
4)If all is valid up to this point send an email to verify.
```

I am looking to support all emails from across the world as my users can be from any country. I was looking if there is a way to restrict the regex more, while still being able to support all email address.

Comment: No spaces and no @ in the first part? Why? Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: Drop all steps but the fourth. The "send an email to verify" looks enough to validate the email.

Comment: The full RFC email regex is like a page long. I'm not sure I'd go that route.

Comment: Restrict email more in what way?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is this not harmful advice, though? I was under the impression that some outbound SMTP server providers weren't too keen on heaps of bounced emails.

Comment: Send a mail with a link asking for validation. That's the best restriction you'll ever get.